# Heroku error 503, webSockets on multiple domains

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I'm experiencing a 503 error with heroku on my project using WebSockets and a custom domain.

- Connecting on http://www.mydomain.com (That point with CNAME on my heroku app)

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://www.mydomain.com/shoutbox' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503`

- Connecting on http://myapp.herokuapp.com

Everything goes allright with adress `ws://myapp.herokuapp.com/shoutbox`. Everything is also good in my local setup.

Is there any cross-domain issue I'm not aware off ? I'm using play!2 as server side fwk, but I don't think there is any relation to this problem.

[EDIT]
If I can only connect within my own domain then it would be fine. Cause this would be the address I'd like people to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you already enabled `heroku labs:enable websockets` since your `herokuapp` domain is working properly.

I have a hunch your DNS query is hitting a Heroku endpoint that doesn't support websockets, i.e. it's cached from before you enabled the websockets functionality.

If this behavior only happens on a single client, try flushing your DNS cache and trying again. Alternatively, make sure the DNS records for both of your domains are resolving to the same IP.

Comment: Actually it seems to have solved the problem after some time. I cleaned the DNS cache. It didn't worked directly but now the problem seems to be gone. *Incredulity* ;)

Comment: There are also upstream DNS caches (from your ISP etc.). Since it was fixed after a while, it was probably a DNS issue. Next time you can verify this by `dig example.com` and `dig @8.8.8.8 example.com` to compare your DNS results to the Google public DNS service. Any diffs will indicate there a stale DNS cache somewhere.