# ActionCable, Heroku Custom Domain, & Cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, heroku, actioncable

Here's the scenario. I'm using ActionCable for a site (let's call it `www.example.com`). It's works perfect in dev, but once I push it to Heroku, I'm getting 302 errors for the WebSocket connection.

The problem seems to stem from the fact that I have Heroku using a custom domain. Because of this, if I point the WebSocket to `wss://example.com`, it gives me a 302, I'm assuming because it's being redirected to the `example.herokuapp.com` url?

So in light of this issue, I was forced to instead point the WebSocket connection to `wss://example.herokuapp.com`. The problem that I'm running into now is that because it's essentially a new domain I'm pointing at, the cookies from example.com are not shared with `example.herokuapp.com`. This means that `example.herokuapp.com` is passing a blank cookie that is actually being set on example.com that I use for authentication.

I verified this is the issue by logging the unsigned cookie (just temporarily unsigned for testing, don't freak out about security), and also setting that cookie on the `example.herokuapp.com` server. After that it worked beautifully.

Obviously I can't have someone go to both sites just to set a damn cookie...

What I would love is to find a way to fix the original issue and be able to point the WebSocket at my custom domain of `wss://example.com` and not have to worry about cookie signing issues. Is this possible?

If not, what would be the best way to set the cookie on the `example.herokuapp.com` domain?

P.S. yes I have looked at other SO questions about ActionCable & Heroku, but none seem to deal with Custom domains. This one talks about a cookie workaround, but I don't feel like it would work with this scenario since they aren't the same subdomains: [Deploying Ruby on Rails app to Heroku while using Action Cable (Puma port listening)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644603/deploying-ruby-on-rails-app-to-heroku-while-using-action-cable-puma-port-listen)

Thanks for taking the time to help me out guys :)

[EDIT] It seems very similar to this question here, but I'm getting a 302 not a 503. [Heroku error 503, webSockets on multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104517/heroku-error-503-websockets-on-multiple-domains)

Comment: What was the solution to this? I am running into a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

So the issue seemed to stem from the fact that the WebSocket request was not being treated as a WebSocket request, but instead a normal, non-upgraded request. And such was being redirected by devise.

I figured out the reason there wasn't any HTTP_UPGRADE header was because of CloudFlare. They don't have WebSockets enabled on Non-Enterprise accounts ($5000+). I have read on other SlackOverflow question's that you can ask CloudFlare to enable it on your account, but most likely won't happen until they start enabling them for all account types.

It seems the only other option until CloudFlare turns on WS is to find a way to share/set cookies between the custom domain and the Heroku domain. I haven't found a solution for this yet, waiting on Heroku to help me out. I'll update this answer for possible future Googlers if I can get a solution for CloudFlare + Custom Domain Heroku + Action Cable users.

Answer (score 1):

I ran to the exact same issue, I also run my actioncable server on Heroku, with Cloudflare in front of it with https enabled.

I wrote a post about how I addressed this issue:

https://herenow.pw/article/rails-actioncable-on-different-domain/

Basically, I ditched cookies, and rendered the signed `user_id` cookie in the html instead.

In my ApplicationController I wrote the following `:signed_user_id` `helper_method`:

```
  def signed_user_id
    @signed_user_id ||= crypt.encrypt_and_sign(current_user.id) if current_user
  end

  def crypt
    @crypt ||= ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(
      Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base,
    )
  end
```

Somewhere in the layout, I render the following JS snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.AppConfig = {
    WEBSOCKET_HOST: "<%= ENV['WEBSOCKET_HOST'] %>",
    WEBSOCKET_PATH: "<%= ActionCable.server.config.mount_path %>",
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    WEBSOCKET_USER_ID_SECRET: "<%= signed_user_id %>",
  <% end %>
  }
</script>
```

Set the `WEBSOCKET_HOST` env to whatever cloudflare disabled subdomain you have created, for example, `ws.myapp.com`.

When connecting to the actioncable server, I instead do something like:

```
var protocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss://" : "ws://";
var host     = window.AppConfig.WEBSOCKET_HOST || window.location.host;
var path     = window.AppConfig.WEBSOCKET_PATH || '/cable';
var userId   = window.AppConfig.WEBSOCKET_USER_ID_SECRET;
var url      = protocol + host + path;

if(userId) {
  url += '?user_id=' + encodeURIComponent(userId);
}

App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer(url);
```

Then on my actioncable server when authenticating connections I do the following:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user
      if current_user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        current_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end

    private

    def user_id
      signed_user_id = request.params.fetch(:user_id)

      crypt.decrypt_and_verify(signed_user_id)
    end

    def crypt
      @crypt ||= ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(
        Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base,
      )
    end
  end
end
```

There are some caveats to this approach though, I would argue that rendering the `user_id` secret in the DOM is less secure than storing in on the browsers cookies, but IMO, we should move to a token based authentication scheme altogether if security is a concern.

Comment: You save my life bro!

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the exact same setup. If you are using `devise` you can get the user id from `env['warden'].user.id` (which is only set once you are successfully logged in) rather than from a signed cookie.

i.e. in your connection do something like:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private
      def find_verified_user
        # if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_channel_key])
        if verified_user = User.find_by(id: env['warden'].user.id)
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```